# how to redirect parent iframe from child window?

Tags: php, javascript, url, popup

After spending a whole day searching and trying ways that I could implement this, I end up asking here, i hope I'll get what I want to achieve. I know this is an issue not a question but still bear with me.

Problem - I am using google oauth to get contacts of user, everything is setup, the flow of application is

```
user clicks on button -> modal appears which has iframe (gmail_connect.php)
which has link to get user authorized -> when clicked on that link I am opening a 
popup in which I am authorizing the user -> when user is authorized -> user will be
redirected to contacts.php in that popup window -> but I have 
written js in contacts.php which will close itself and reload the iframe from which 
the window was opened with contacts.php with all the parameters.
```

following are those two lines that I have written in contacts.php which closes itself(popup window) and sets the location of parent iframe to url that popup window has.

```
<?php
   $oauth_verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];
   $oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token'];
?>
<script>
window.opener.location.href = 'contacts.php?oauth_verifier=<?= $oauth_verifier?>&oauth_token=<?= $oauth_token;?>';
window.close();
<script>
```

the problem is I get 404 error, and thats obvious because when I check url of iframe, the url is

```
<a href="http://localhost/contacts.php%3foauth_verifier=f2hkTKLNSeZa7-2hc1II-7kQ&amp;oauth_token=4%252FilQ0z3IvyKFSDPUOqQe_RgBH2ZbI">referring page</a>
```

you can see `%3f` instead of `?` and `&amp;` instead of `&`

why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like the url is getting URLEncoded.

Comment: i tried url encoding, decoding, on server side and client side also, but no luck